# SELECT and CONCAT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm using MySQL and trying to use CONCAT_WS() function with SELECT.

I tried:

```
SELECT id, A_12, CONCAT_WS('A_', '12') as testA from TABLE_A
```

I expected something like

```
id | A_12 | testA |
-------------------
 1 |  20  |   20  |
```

The value is `testA` should be same as the value in `A_12`.

However, what I'm getting is

```
id | A_12 | testA |
-------------------
 1 |  20  |   12  |
```

The '12' in testA column is simply coming from latter string of the CONCAT_WS() function `CONCAT_WS('A_','12')`.

Any help would be appreciated.

**======EDIT======**:

Sorry I didn't clearly state my question and purpose in the beginning. I have 12 columns `A_1, A_2, ... , A_12` in `TABLE_A`. More specifically, `Table_A` looks like this:

```
id | A_1 | A_2 | ... | A_12|
---------------------------
 1 |  4  |  5  | ... |  20 |
 2 |  1  |  4  | ... |  50 |
 3 |  2  |  5  | ... |  70 |
```

I also have another table `TABLE_B` that looks something like this:

```
id | value
----------
 1 | 12
 2 | 5
 3 | 3
```

I'm trying to create a stored function that...

1. select the corresponding `value` from `TABLE_B`
2. from `TABLE_A`, pull info under the column `A_` + the value from `Table_B`

for every `id`.

So I have

```
SELECT id, CONCAT_WS('A_', stored-value-from-TABLE_B) as testA from TABLE_A
```

To make sure if the code is running as I expect, I ran

```
SELECT id, A_12, CONCAT_WS('A_', '12') as testA from TABLE_A
```

since the value for `id=1` in `Table_B` is 12.

However, what I'm getting is `12` in `testA` column for every `id`.

Comment: why you expecting 20? what are you trying to do ?

Comment: You can't dynamically reference a database object in sql. You have to dynamically generate your sql statement in a scripting language (or stored procedure) and then execute it to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: why not just do use the alias you want on the column name `select A_12, A_12 as testA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the tables on their `id`s and pick the proper `A_?` with the function [`ELT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_elt) where you have to enumerate all 12 columns:

```
SELECT b.*, 
       ELT(b.value, a.A_1, a.A_2, ..., a.A_12) testA
FROM TABLE_B b INNER JOIN TABLE_A a
ON b.id = a.id;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b8611e48aa2d72f25698a8a48bfb5135).

Answer (score 0):

well to get this result just need

```
SELECT id, A_12, A_12 as testA from TABLE_A
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

You seem to think that a select-list is bound to be a list of column names,  therefore a string function like CONCAT_WS() would produce a string like `A_12` and that string must be interpreted as a column identifier, so the result of that query would use the value of the column named by that string.

But that's not how an SQL select-list works.

A select-list is a list of *expressions*. You could use a simple column name, and the result would be the value in that column. Or you could use another expression, in this case a string function, and the result will be the string returned by that function — *not* the column that coincidentally has a name matching that string.

As mentioned in the comment above, identifiers are fixed in an SQL query. You cannot make a string expression and have the value of that expression be interpreted as an identifier in the same query. To make a dynamic reference to an identifier, you need to format it in your SQL syntax *before* you prepare the query.

You also misunderstand what `CONCAT_WS('A_', '12')` does. It concatenates its 2nd argument and further arguments, with a separator between them of the 1st argument. A typical usage would be:

```
CONCAT_WS(', ', col1, col2, col3, ...)`
```

This returns a list of comma-separated words from the values of several columns: "value1, value2, value3".

So in your case, you concatenated a single value "12" but the separator "A_" does not appear because there is only one value in the list.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't want `CONCAT_WS()`, you want `CONCAT()` - Concat with separator inserts whatever your first argument is between all the others, and since you only have one other argument, it never gets used - for example `CONCAT_WS('A_', '12', '13')` would give you `12A_13`. `CONCAT('A_', '12')` gives you `A_12` but as a string, not as a column name.

After correcting to CONCAT and evaluating, your select will look like this `SELECT id, A_12, 'A_12' as testA from TABLE_A;` Notice the quotes around A_12.

This is because concat functions return a string and can't be used to build a column name in a select string the way you want. It's possible to do so, but is complicated - you would have to build your entire query string in a string variable then execute it as a prepared statement:

```
SET @QueryString = CONCAT('SELECT id, A_12, ', CONCAT('A_', '12'), ' as testA from TABLE_A;');
PREPARE stmnt FROM @QueryString;
EXECUTE stmnt;
```

The nested `CONCAT()` is unnecessary, since concat can take any number of arguments so you get it simplified to this:

```
SET @QueryString = CONCAT('SELECT id, A_12, ', 'A_', '12', ' as testA from TABLE_A;');
PREPARE stmnt FROM @QueryString;
EXECUTE stmnt;
```

And your @QueryString will be `SELECT id, A_12, A_12 as testA from TABLE_A;`

This can be pretty dangerous if anything in that string comes from user input in a system. If this is connected to any application, combine the strings using whatever concatenation your server side application language uses then execute that as a query.

[DB Fiddle testing](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fCzqywWs6kBBhExvuFPUpC/2) (SQLFiddle seems to have removed support for selects in prepared statements)